# Error con multi_image_picker flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Por favor si alguien me puede ayudar estoy recibiendo este error al tratar de correr mi aplicación.

````
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.2, on macOS 14.1.2 23B92 darwin-arm64, locale es-419)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2023.2.5)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.84.2)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] Network resources```

**Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/multi_image_picker-4.8.01/lib/src/asset_thumb_provider.dart:30:36: Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found.**
````

Comment: Prueba a hacer flutter clean y luego flutter pub get. Puede que sea problema con la version de Flutter que estás usando. Si lo anterior no funciona, prueba con versiones más actualizadas o anteriores, para ir descartando posibles problemas.

Comment: Hola Manuel Gracias por tu tiempo y tu comentario te comento que ya intente eso pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema si talvez tienes otra idea te la agradecería

Comment: Esto me paso en más de una ocasión (no el mismo error) y lo solucione cambiando la versión de Flutter y en otra ocasión cambiando la versión del package

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo al mensaje de error:

> **Failed to build iOS app Error (Xcode): ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/multi_image_picker-4.8.01/lib/src/asset_thumb_provider.dart:30:36:
> Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found.**

**El problema se presenta con la dependencia multi_image_picker-4.8.01 y muy probablemente con la versiòn de flutter usada.**

Al revisar la dependencia, no creo que sea una correcta soluciòn actualizar Flutter, ya que el proyecto de [multi_image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker) ha sido detenido desde hace 2 años, por lo cual la sugerencia es usar una opciòn mejor que es [flutter_wechat_assets_picker](https://github.com/fluttercandies/flutter_wechat_assets_picker)

y actualizar Flutter:

```
flutter pub upgrade
```